# If L = {0^n 1^n | n > 0 } is L^c (complement of L) regular?

Tags: computer-science, theory, finite-automata

My teacher stated that If L = {0^n 1^n | n > 0 } then the complement was regular. I don't think it is.

Is there anyone that can clear this up to me? I thought that if L was irregular then the complement also was irregular.

Comment: Should this perhaps be migrated to the Computer Science SE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The complement of a nonregular language is never regular. If L is nonregular and L<sup>c</sup> were regular, then (L<sup>c</sup>)<sup>c</sup> = L would be regular, a contradiction. Therefore, L<sup>c</sup> in your example isn't regular. You can use the pumping lemma or Myhill-Nerode to prove this.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm soooo happy to have passed this subject! no more mr Turing for me! :P